# Passenger starting on all urls except the root url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a rails 4.1.0 application to my production environment with apache (2.4.17), rvm and passenger (4.0.59).

The problem is, I keep getting the apache directory listing of the public directory when I go to the url (www.myapp.com) of my vhost. But: When I navigate to a route inside my rails-app, e.g; `www.myapp.com/pages/1` passenger starts the application and everything works as expected.

This is my passenger.conf:

```
# /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/passenger.conf
LoadModule passenger_module /home/sander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview2/gems/passenger-4.0.59/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
    <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
       PassengerRoot /home/sander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview2/gems/passenger-4.0.59
       PassengerDefaultRuby /home/sander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview2/wrappers/ruby
     </IfModule>
```

I checked the apache module was loaded:

```
>> apache2ctl -M
...
passenger_module (shared)
```

Virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost my-ip:80>
  ServerName www.myapp.com
  ServerAlias myapp.com

  DocumentRoot /srv/www/rails/myapp/current/public
  PassengerAppRoot /srv/www/rails/myapp/current
  RailsEnv production

  <Directory /srv/www/rails/myapp/current/public>
     Require all granted
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer on serverfault helped me solve this for now:
https://serverfault.com/questions/731814/apachepassenger-not-serving-the-root-of-the-sinatra-application

Kami referenced a bug in Apache 2.4.17 in the autoindex module in combination with Phusion Passenger.

I disabled the autoindex module by commenting the `Loadmodule ...` line in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/autoindex.load`

restarted Apache, and everything works now.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't do it for me - I tried it, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You are the best person in the world :D